Find $m+n$ if $\sqrt{m+\sqrt{m+\sqrt{\cdots+\sqrt{m}}}}=n$ where the number of square-root signs is 2024.
Can anyone help me with the question below? I have 2 approaches.
Question :
Let $m$ and $n$ be integers. Find $m+n$ if $$\sqrt{m+\sqrt{m+\sqrt{\cdots+\sqrt{m}}}}=n ,$$
where the number of square-root signs is 2024.
Approach 1 (Mathematically):
Since 2024 is large, I assume $$n=\sqrt{m+n} ,$$ because $n= \sqrt{m+\sqrt{m+\sqrt{\cdots+\sqrt{m}}}}$. Then, we have $$n^2-n-m=0.$$
Solve by quadratic formula,
$$m=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4m}}{2}.$$
Since $n$ must be an interger, $1+4m$ must be a perfect square. Let $1+4m=k^2$ , $m=\frac{k^2-1}{4}$.
For $k=3$, $m=2$.
When $m=2$, $n=\frac{1\pm3}{2}=2$ (because $n>0$)
So, $m+n=2+2=4$
Approach 2 (By programming, R):
options(scipen=9999999)  # Turn off scientific notation

nested_sqrt <- function(m, N) {
  if (N == 1) {
    return(sqrt(m))
  } else {
    return(sqrt(m + nested_sqrt(m, N - 1)))
  }
}

N <- 2024
results <- numeric(100)

for (m in 1:100) {
  results[m] <- nested_sqrt(m, N)
}

# Create a data frame with the results
data <- data.frame(
  m = 1:100,
  results = results,
  ToF = 1:100000000 == results
)

# Print the data frame
print(data)


subset(data, ToF == TRUE)

 m results  ToF
2 2       2 TRUE

From here, we can see that when $m=2$, $n=2$ as well.
But I don't think I can assume like that isn't?

You can try by reducing the number $2024$ to some case like $1,2,3$ to observe the pattern first.
For example, your assumption can be regarded as the case of 1 square root. Then you see that $n^2=m+n$. Since $n|n^2$, we have $n|(m+n)\implies n|m$. This means $m=kn$ and thus $n=k+1$. Inputting any value of $k$ can yield a pair of solution $(m,n)=(k(k+1),k+1)$. And you can already see $m+n$ is not a fixed value.

Hi @AngaeMT I am sorry, I don't get it... " $m+n$ is not a fixed value " means $m$ will never be equal to $n$?

If you took just two square roots so $n=\sqrt{m+\sqrt{m}}$ then any solution would also satisfy $n^2=m+\sqrt{m}$ and $(n^2-m)^2=m$ leading to (after ignoring the spurious solution) $m=n^2+\frac12-\sqrt{n^2+\frac14}$, between $n^2-n$ and $n^2-n + \frac12$, and I would have thought the only integer solution pair would be $(0,0)$.

Where does this question come from?

Any reference for this question? Does the inner most radical sign contain $m$ or $m+m$?

Fix a positive integer $m$.

For each positive integer $k$, let
$$
x_k=\sqrt{m+\sqrt{m+\sqrt{\cdots+\sqrt{m}}}}
$$
where the number of square root signs is equal to $k$.

Claim:$\;$There are no integers $k\ge 2$ for which $x_k$ is an integer.

Proof:

Initiating a proof by contradiction, assume the claim is false.

Let $k$ be the least integer with $k\ge 2$ for which $x_k$ is an integer.

First suppose $k > 2$.

From the definition of $x_k$ we get
$$
x_k^2=m+x_{k-1}
$$
hence since $x_k$ is an integer, so is $x_{k-1}$, contrary to the minimality of $k$.

It follows that $k=2$.

Then letting $n=x_2$ we get
\begin{align*}
&
n=\sqrt{m+\sqrt{m}}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
n^2=m+\sqrt{m}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(n^2-m)^2=m
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
m^2-(2n^2+1)m+n^4=0
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
contradiction, since the above equation, regarded as a quadratic equation in $m$, has discriminant
$$
D=4n^2+1
$$
which is strictly between $(2n)^2$ and $(2n+1)^2$, so $D$ can't be a perfect square.

This completes the proof.

Hey @quasi, thank you! I have few questions... for the case when $k>2$ , is it because firstly we assumed that $k$ is the smallest integer for which $x_k$ is an integer. But, from the equation $x_k^2=m+x_{k-1}$ shown that $x_{k-1}$ is also an integer. This means that  $x_{k-1}$ is an integer for some $k-1$, which smaller than $k$. This contradicts the first assumption that k is the smallest such integer? Am I right?

@Gambit: Yes, $k$ is assumed to be the least integer with $k\ge 2$ such that $x_k$ is an integer. But if $k > 2$, then $k-1\ge 2$, and since $x_k$ is an integer, so is $x_{k-1}$, contrary to the assumption about $k$.

Nice proof. Dissapointing outcome though.

Suppose $m$ and $n$ are integers satisfying the given relation. Then everything that appears under a square-root sign must be a perfect square. In particular $m = k^2$ is a perfect square and so is $m + \sqrt{m} = k(k+1)$. Since $k$ is a perfect square and $\gcd(k, k+1) = 1$ this implies that $k+1$ is also a perfect square, which implies $k=0$. Therefore $m=n=0$.
By the way, the question would be much better phrased as "Find all possible values of $m+n$ if...". The way it is written now suggests there is only one possible value, which is giving most of the game away.
